# How to create a variable set of variables

Tags: python, excel, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Let's say that I have something like the following:

```
target = "path_to_excel.xlsx"
raw_data = pandas.ExcelFile(target)
```

Then if I use the method:

```
raw_data.sheet_names
```

I will get a list of the sheet names contained within that spreadsheet. My question is how would I create a variable number of data frames based upon the number of sheets? IE:

```
In [1] len(raw_data.sheet_names)
Out [1] 3

list_of_df_names = []
for x in range(len(raw_data.sheet_names)):
    list_of_df_names.append("df"+str(x))

for i, element in enumerate(list_of_df_names):
    element = pandas.read_excel(raw_data, raw_data.sheet.names[i])
```

Comment: why not just create a dict of dfs, so the key is the sheet name and the value are the dfs?